# Put Excel columns in an array Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, parsing

I have never used Excel parser in MatLab. I have an Excel file which has 3 columns. And I would like to save all elements of column 2 in an column array and all elements of column 3 in an other column array. How can I browse the Excel file column by column and then line by line?

It works with this :

```
[~,~,data] = xlsread('excelfile.xlsx');
% Save columns
arraycolumn2 = data(:,2); % Parse column 2
arraycolumn3 = data(:,3); % Parse column 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function *importdata*

```
data = importdata('yourExcelFile.xlsx');

colum1 = data(:,1);
colum2 = data(:,2);
colum3 = data(:,3);
```